# which diagram is best to analyise mvc application classes based on zend?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am currently working on a project based on zend framework . I have done use case diagrams to analyse my application and also the database design .

I have been reading and also practicing zend framework but  only with simple application which consist of  2 roles **i.e** user and admin . Since zend provides ACL i was thinking of using the  function to limit access to  my resources .

My question is:

what diagram is best to analyse mvc based zend application and also to effeciently utiliz the classes provided in the zend framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Every diagram has its own role. If you need to show the sequence of the actions, the sequence diagrams is what you need. If you want to display how your application is structured, the class diagram satisfy your need and so on.

Comment: I have done the sequence diagram to see the scenarios that are involving in my application .you are right class diagrams  so benfit to know how my application is structured but wouldn't it be that i have have to find the m in mvc i.e model and the c in mvci.e      controller  from the class diagrams again or what.                                                                                 I have seen one analysis specifically it  is called **robustness analysis** the say it is easier to identify your models and controllers with it .but i was wondering if there is another alternative .